# How to save data from mongodb into node.js cache?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, caching

I need help with create simple function in nodejs that show all rows in some table from mongodb.

In  second time the function running its get the data from node.js caching and not go to mongodb.
somthing like that idea:

```
getData function(){

    if(myCache == undefined){
      // code that get data from mongodb (i have it)
      // and insert into cache of node.js (TODO)
    } 
    else {
        // code that get data from cache node.js (TODO)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The general idea is to implement some form of asynchronous caching in which the cache object will have a key-value storage. So, for example, extending your idea you could restructure your function to follow this pattern:

```
var myCache = {};

var getData = function(id, callback) {
    if (myCache.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
        if (myCache[id].hasOwnProperty("data")) { /* value is already in cache */
            return callback(null, myCache[id].data);
        }

        /* value is not yet in cache, so queue the callback */
        return myCache[id].queue.push(callback);
    }

    /* cache for the first time */
    myCache[id] = { "queue": [callback] };

    /* fetch data from MongoDB */
    collection.findOne({ "_id": id }, function(err, data){
        if (err) return callback(err);

        myCache[id].data = data;

        myCache[id].queue.map(function (cb) {
            cb(null, data);
        });

        delete myCache[id].queue;
    });

}
```